# prepositions: at ABC Limited, of ABC Limited, from ABC Limited

Tags: prepositions

I have made up the scenario below.

(1) I'm introducing someone to my friend right now. I say to Jack, "This is Mr. Brown Taylor. He is the senior sales manager **at** ABC Limited."

(2) ... "This is Mr. Brown Taylor. He is the senior sales manager **of** ABC Limited."

(3) ... "This is Mr. Brown Taylor. He is the senior sales manager **from** ABC Limited."

Which preposition is correct?

Comment: 1) is the best to mean works at a place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are correct. However, one must never use the expression M/s ABC Limited, because ABC Limited is a singular entity whereas 'M/s' is used to denote a collection of persons, as in case of a Partnership Firm, an Association of Persons, or a Body of Individuals.
Use of prefix 'M/s' before a limited company is wrong because a company is a single unique entity, and not a collection of persons.

Answer (score 2):

All three options are correct, but they have slightly different shades of meaning. Whereas "at" merely indicates that Mr. Brown Taylor works *at* ABC Ltd., "of" could be taken to imply that Mr. Brown Taylor's job entails management *of* the whole company. Similarly, "from" might suggest that Mr. Brown Taylor is present as a representative of ABC Ltd. (i.e., that he has come *from* that company to speak with you and your friend). However, these are all quite subtle points; in the majority of situations, all three prepositions would be valid options.