# Which article would be more natural here?

Tags: articles, phrase-choice

> *He's had conflicts everywhere he's been. **A**/**the** manager **at**/**of** a restaurant where he worked as a waiter told the police that he...*

Could someone please tell me which article you would find more natural to use in this context?

Comment: The preposition part is a duplicate of another question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270201/41273

Comment: Use a manager if there are several but only one spoke to police; use the manager if there is only one.

Comment: I would use 'the manager of a restaurant...' (i.e. his former boss).